# Start without debugging same with start from .exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

What are the differences between run without debugging and running from .exe? The question relies on the fact that my program runs fine from ctrl+f5 but not from .exe of debug mode.

Comment: With ".exe of debug mode", do you mean running the executable manually outside of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your program without debuging it takes the last succesfull build and starts this. if you run with debugging it builds the last version of the code and runs that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was clarrifying